# why does the terminal gives me this error message when i try to type make calculator (the c file is called calculator)

Tags: c, terminal, cs50

```
The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ make <<<<  calculator
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You're typing `make` in a PowerShell terminal and it has't the foggiest clue what `make` means.

Comment: so what sohould i do?

Comment: Set your environment `path` variable to include the location of the `make.exe` utility.  Then call it from a `CMD` prompt

Comment: What toolchain do you have installed? MSVC. GCC, cygwin,clang?

Comment: also - do you have a makefile? I would expect you to be using an IDE

Comment: Have you installed WSL?

Comment: i use vscode i haven't installed anything to it i am really to c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.